# How to find out if a Hive table is external or internal?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have multiple questions here. I am looking for any hive shell commands or queries to find the below details.

1. Given a hive database name, how can I get the list of external tables in that database?
2. Given a hive table name, how can I find out whether the table is external or internal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**1) Given a hive database name, how can I get the list of external tables in that database ?**

You can try this command:

```
SHOW TABLES [IN database_name] [identifier_with_wildcards];
```

It will give you all tables. As far as I know there is no direct command to know all the tables of type external/internal. For that you have use JDBC connection to connect to HiveMetastore and get the required info.

**2) Given a hive table name, how can I find that whether the table is external or internal table ?**

You can try any of this commands:

```
describe formatted table_name

describe extended table_name
```

It show all the detail info of a table. Along with :

```
Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE           
Table Parameters:       EXTERNAL=TRUE
```

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: Furthermore, If it's an Internal Table, it would say: `Table Type:          MANAGED_TABLE` upon executing `describe formatted table_name`.